# Will moto brick loading wrong firmware?

Tags: device-firmware

I cant load recovery to flash new ROM

As its the first time im about to use ADB, ive read that  i need: Motorola drivers, mfastboot, my phone firmware

In this [link](http://www.filefactory.com/folder/c6cdedc45a775d27/?sort=created&order=DESC&show=25&page=1) i have two options for XT1064 "Niimx" and "Iusmxaus" ... Found that retca, retuaws and niimx are for canadian, usa and mexico phones... but how do i know if this phone comes from usa mexico or canada? I already used it before it failed to load recovery, and ive had signal in mexico. Im still affraid of bricking my phone if loading a non fitting firmware, could this happen?

Comment: You can enter the bootloader and execute `fastboot getvar all` and you will see the current variant installed. Flashing a different variant firmware will not recommended. I would honestly go to XDA to your device specific forums and look there, just googling random files can lead to less than desirable results. Flashing the incorrect variant firmware will likely not cause a brick condition, but will probably not have any connectivity (no WiFi or mobile connection). Note the last sentence is Moto specific, and does not cover all models but does apply to the Moto G line in general.

Comment: Yes. Almost certainly it will brick (see link above for reasons). Search XDA for your specific model ROM